# What DSL Query to use in ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch

I use PHP library for ElasticSearch. I have added documents in index as:

```
$document = array('name' => 'Bob', 'family' => 'Bobsters', 'car' => 'Mersedes');
```

What kind of query I need to use if I want to get search result after entered symbol: `B`.

It request whould be return result with name `Bob` and other result that are started from symbol `B`.

Answer (score 0):

More information is required for a comprehensive answer, as you can customize the index/type/fields you search on etc., and create a more efficient query with additional parameters, as a wildcard query is **very expensive**, especially if only wildcarding one letter, and if you wildcarding at the **end of a query string**.

This is **bad**. I realize there is an excessive use of bolding, however it's hard to overstate how expensive wildcarding at the end of a querystring (and only one letter at that) is.

You can read about wildcard queries [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).

As always with these questions it is good to mention search as you type functionality which is often the end goal, docs found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_time_search_as_you_type.html).

Below is a basic wildcard query that will fulfill the original function you are asking for.

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
       "wildcard": {
          "name": {
            "value": "B*"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This will return all documents with the name field starting with B.

Edit in response to comments:

If you are not interested in wildcard query, you may use the [prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) query.

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
       "prefix": {
          "name": "B"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share example where is not wildcard, but more optimal case of search? Because you have wrote that it is bad to use wildcard. I need that search will work by one symbol in field input. So you did not get correct and userful answer

Comment: I have added another way to query without wildcard. I would suggest you look at your use case and try to build around that, generally returning on 1 character is very difficult, if you must, use the prefix query which is specifically designed for that functionality.

Comment: How I can test this quert via standart web-interface ElasticSearch?

Comment: Daniel, can you share one good example which resolves my problem?